# How can I attach an event to an object, that is covered by another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to unhide a div, when the mouse pointer enters its sibling image and hide it when it leaves. But in fact, when I move the mouse pointer while it is on the image, it just starts to twinkle.

Both image and div have the same size.

HTML code:

`<img src="../recource/person/1.png">
 <div class="o_p_faces_e_glass_off">
   <div><p>Well, I enjoy working for this company, everything is okay.</p></div>
 </div>`

JS code:

```
var entertimes = 0;
$(".o_p_faces_e img").mouseenter(function(){
    if(entertimes==0) {
    var glassON = $(this).next();
    glassON.removeClass("o_p_faces_e_glass_off");
    glassON.addClass("o_p_faces_e_glass_on");
    entertimes++;
    }
});

$(".o_p_faces_e img").mouseleave(function(){
    if(entertimes==1) {
    var glassOFF = $(this).next();
    glassOFF.removeClass("o_p_faces_e_glass_on");
    glassOFF.addClass("o_p_faces_e_glass_off");
    entertimes--;
    }
})
```

CSS code:

```css
.o_p_faces_e img {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:51px;
    border:5px solid #f7ec16;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.o_p_faces_e_glass_off {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.o_p_faces_e_glass_on {
    position:absolute;
    left:56px;
    top:5px;
    width:330px;
    height:330px;
    background-color:rgb(252, 247, 156, 0.7);
    display: block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-radius:50%;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition:all 1s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Hard to know what issue is without seeing what css is used and what the class change does

Comment: I have provided my CSS code, check it out please.

Comment: @ArmanGrigoryan It's probably better to think about what's causing this problem. When your mouse enters the image, its sibling is shown. When that sibling is shown, it appears in front of the image, thus causing your mouse to *leave* the image and *enter* the sibling. This causes a mouseleave event on the image, thus hiding the sibling. When the sibling is hidden, the mouse leaves the sibling and then enters the image, thus showing the sibling again in an infinite loop. simply moving the events up to an element that encompasses both elements should make it stop blinking.

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin! I simply moved the event up to the parent element, that encompasses both of them as you said, and it really worked! I've been struggling for hours... thank you for you help one more time.

Comment: And your explanation was very clear, I got it!

Answer (score -4):

Both can be added to the same div like so:

```
$(".o_p_faces_e img").mouseenter(function() {
    //mouse enter code
}).mouseleave(function() {
    //mouse leave code
});
```

Comment: eh, this could work, if it was actually targeting the parent div. and had some conditionals on the event target. but it doesn't.

Comment: It  doesn't help, the div is still twinkling on the image, it's being rapidly toggled between classes o_p_faces_e_glass_on and o_p_faces_e_glass_off. Since the "ON" class has "display:block" css property, and the "OFF" class has "display:none" property, it looks like twinkling (or blinking, I don't know how to explain this as my English isn't that good).